# How to configure Jira board to display assignee icon in Plan view?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

[image: User icon in Plan view]
 I would like to configure my Jira board to display assignee icon in Plan view but I couldn't find any options in Jira board settings. Does it require separate plugin?.

Comment: What version of JIRA Agile are you using? This was a fairly recent addition to JIRA Agile you may just need to update the plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was added in **JIRA Agile 6.5**. My guess would be that you are running an earlier version of the plug-in.

Release notes; https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-releases/jira-agile-release-notes/jira-agile-6-5-release-notes

If you have an active support subscription, you should be able to update JIRA Agile through `Administration > Add-ons`.

Comment: Thanks @JamieB I am running old JIRA 6.1.2